# Ideal way to handle F2PY compiler with multiple Fortran files

Tags: f2py

I'm using F2PY to compile my Fortran codes, but it's a little confusing how I can sort out the dependency between files.

For example, there are file A.f90 and B.f90, that B.f90 uses a module in A.f90. How would I compile these to get a dynamic library? My approach is

```
with open('A.f90') as fh:
    source = fh.read()
with open('B.f90') as fh:
    source += fh.read()
f2py.compile(source, ...)
```

But I don't think it's a good practice. I believe there will be better approaches for this. I would like to compile those independently but use modules from A as a dynamic library when compiling B. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can send the fortran files with dependencies through the `extra_args` option within the `f2py.compile` module.

Your code would then look like

```
with open('B.f90') as fh:
    source = fh.read()
f2py.compile(source,....,extra_args=path_to_A.f90)
```